# How to position a SVG element on top of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I need to positioning an SVG element on top of an iframe.

I have tried with no success:

- using SVG markup first in the source
- using z-index on the SVG element

Any ideas how to solve it?

http://jsfiddle.net/kk5yb95o/

```
  <svg id="svg-area" width="600" height="600">
        <rect id="svg-test" width="600" height="100" fill="purple" />
    </svg>
    <div id="wrapper-bbs"></div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.cnn.com"></iframe>


#iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px
}
```

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kk5yb95o/1/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` property change behavior only for elements with `position` property is `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed` or `sticky`.
So, add CSS `position` property to `svg` element and set `z-index` bigger than iframe `z-index`.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kk5yb95o/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your hit, apparently in my production code I had position on static set by some JS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `z-index` to layer your items:

```css
#iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    z-index:1;
}
svg{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

```html
  <svg id="svg-area" width="600" height="600">
        <rect id="svg-test" width="600" height="100" fill="purple" />
    </svg>
    <div id="wrapper-bbs"></div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.cnn.com"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the positioning and z-index of your svg-element:

```
#svg-area {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```